# how do i parse the username from the page source code?

Tags: javascript, parsing, manual

I will be running the javascript through my browser (chrome) like this `javascript:`codegoeshere, so i cannot use `jQuery`. The website is not mine, so i cannot modify it.
In the source code of the web page the username is stored like this:

```
<div class="m-names"><div class="m-h3"><strong>@usernamegoeshere</strong>
```

My question is, how can i parse `@usernamegoeshere` with `javascript` into a variable? I want to be able to alert the final result.
Thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: Sometimes you can use jQuery. It depends on if the page has already loaded the jQuery script. For example, stackoverflow uses jQuery, and so you have access to it. If you really need it, you can always load it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use querySelectorAll

```
javascript:alert(document.querySelectorAll(".m-names .m-h3 strong")[0].innerHTML);
```

Comment: simple and nice solution